# Add "sudo" to the last command line in bash

Tags: bash, zsh

I run a command, then realize it should have been run with `sudo`.

In zsh I have a function so that I can hit a ^x^x and it will grab the previous line from the history and prepend `sudo` to it, so I can run it again.

Is it possible to do this with bash?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245614/repeat-last-command-with-sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Gerald Schneider, this is a duplicate that exists on Stack Overflow, but since it doesn't exist on Serverfault, and it won't let me mark it as duplicate, I'll just put the answer here as well.

From jm666 question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245614/repeat-last-command-with-sudo/17245624#17245624)

---

You can write:

```
sudo !!
```

(See [§9.3 "History Expansion" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).)

---

Answer (score 0):

Most bash implementations I have used allow command-history navigation via the up- and down-arrow keys.

So in addition to @trueCamelType's solution, one could also use:

```
<up-arrow><home>sudo<space><enter>
```

Eight characters, either way.  :)